# How to wait till the response comes from the rest client, in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services, angular-http

I have a Rest Service witch returns : `{dataRef:Array[3],status:Object}`.
When I inject the service in the controller and run the application, I still have trouble with returning the data from my rest service.
I read and tried other solutions from here, but I still can`t make this work. Some suggestions please ?!

**First service**

```
 .factory('widgetRestService',['$http','UrlService','$log',
  function($http,UrlService,$log){

  var serviceInstance = {};
  serviceInstance.dataRef = [];
  serviceInstance.status = {};

  var contextPath = UrlService.getContextPath();
  var urlHelpRef = contextPath + "/rest/widgets/getListInfoDashboards";

  var promiseData =  $http({method: 'GET', url: urlHelpRef}).
    success(function (data, status) {
      $log.debug("widgetServiceInfo", data);

      serviceInstance.status = status;
      serviceInstance.dataRef = data;

    }).
    error(function (data, status) {
      serviceInstance.data = data || "Request failed";
      serviceInstance.status = status;
    });

    promiseData.$promise.then(function success(data,status) {
      serviceInstance.status = status;
      serviceInstance.dataRef = data;
    });

  return serviceInstance;
```

}]);

**Controller**

```
$log.debug('widgetRestService',widgetRestService);
```

**Result**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: $http returns a promise. Not an object which has a field $promise. So promiseData.$promise is undefined. success() and error() are also deprecated now. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Comment: where is the `get()` method on `widgetRestService` coming from?

Comment: You would return the promise from your service (the response from calling `$http`). That allows you to call `.then()` in your controller or what ever is calling the service. You can chain multiple `.then()`. so if you wanted to manipulate the data in your service before it is exposed out you add a `.then()`. Think of it like a pipeline, data goes in one `.then()` what it returns will be passed into the next `.then()` etc.

Comment: @stephen.vakil sorry, I edited the post, I removed that piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to create this service. The first, `widgetRestServiceSingle`, will only make the $http call once, when it is first instantiated, and thereafter keep returning the same data. The second, `widgetRestServiceEvery`, will always execute the $http call anew when you call its get() method.

Single value (first instantiation) source code:

```
.factory('widgetRestServiceSingle', ['$http', 'UrlService', '$log', function($http, UrlService, $log) {
  var contextPath = UrlService.getContextPath();
  var urlHelpRef = contextPath + "/rest/widgets/getListInfoDashboards";

  return $http({method: 'GET', url: urlHelpRef})
    .then(function (response) {
      return {dataRef: response.data, status: response.status};
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      return {dataRef: response.data || 'Request failed', status: response.status};
    });
}]);

.factory('defaultWidgets', ['widgetRestServiceSingle', '$log', 'myServicevld',  function(widgetRestServiceSingle, $log, myServicevld) {
  return widgetRestServiceSingle.then(function(data) {
    $log.debug('hahiha',data);
  });
}]);
```

and multiple values (one per `get()` execution) source code:

```
.factory('widgetRestServiceEvery', ['$http', 'UrlService', '$log', function($http, UrlService, $log) {
  return {
    get: function get() {
      var contextPath = UrlService.getContextPath();
      var urlHelpRef = contextPath + "/rest/widgets/getListInfoDashboards";

      return $http({method: 'GET', url: urlHelpRef})
        .then(function (response) {
          return {dataRef: response.data, status: response.status};
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
          return {dataRef: response.data || 'Request failed', status: response.status};
        });
      }
    };
}]);

.factory('defaultWidgets', ['widgetRestServiceEvery', '$log', 'myServicevld',  function(widgetRestServiceEvery, $log, myServicevld) {
  return widgetRestServiceEvery.get().then(function(data) {
    $log.debug('hahiha',data);
  });
}]);
```

For more information about `Promises`, [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) is a good place to start.

Also note that according to the [the official Angular $http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), `.success()` and `.error()` have been deprecated in favor of `.then()` and `.catch()` which don't hide away the fact that $http returns a promise.

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Comment: Why ==> return widgetRestServiceSingle.dataRef.then(function(data) {
    $log.debug('hahiha',data);
  }); is not working ? How can I return the array dataRef ?

Comment: widgetRestServiceSingle is a promise, it doesn't actually have the dataRef. If you want it, just say `widgetRestServiceSingle.then(function(data) { return data.dataRef; }).then(function(dataRef) { ...do something with dataRef here... });`